# Cache manifest are not loaded

Tags: html, manifest, application-cache, html5-appcache

I want to use html5 manifest file. To cache the mose important things of the website. I have make a manifest file and cache the most important things. I cache the important images that are used in all the pages. And i cached the css file. But this is going broken.

This is my manifest file:

```
CACHE MANIFEST

# VERSION 10

CACHE:
static/img/bg-friends-selection.jpg
static/img/bg-home.jpg
static/img/bg-selection.jpg
static/img/logo.png
static/css/style.css
```

But now the problem. When i open the page. The first time it's good. But when i open the page for the second time. The images and items that i not cached. Are not loaded. How can i fix that.

[Here you have a live link](http://mikevierwind.nl/demo/)

Comment: What browsers have you tried?

Comment: Updated answer below with `NETWORK:` info, which is probably the source of your issue here.

Answer (score 0):

The live link site doesn't specify a `manifest` attribute in the `<html>` tag.  You need to point your document at the manifest so it knows what to cache.

In any event, you probably want this at the bottom of your manifest file:

```
NETWORK:
*
```

See [HTML5 cache manifest: whitelisting ALL remote resources?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427260/html5-cache-manifest-whitelisting-all-remote-resources) for more information.