# HTML5 Caching misbehaving

Tags: javascript, html, caching, cache-manifest

I have this nice little cache manifest file, which I embed into my `index.html` page:

```
CACHE MANIFEST
# version 8
9341.js
9341.css
none.cur

NETWORK:
http://*
```

Everything goes smoothly and the enlisted resources get cached. However, despite my efforts on the last two lines of the manifest file, the browser refuses to load http://www.google.com/jsapi file on the consequent reloads stating that it *Failed to load resource* (Chrome).

The problem is present in Opera 11, Chrome 15, Mozilla is for some reason fine. The problem disappears when I remove the manifest file. Any of you knows what might be causing this? It's rather bothersome. [>> Online demonstration](http://doodoo.wz.cz/had/)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Setting the `NETWORK` directive to `*` solved the problem. Answer found [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2427260/html5-cache-manifest-whitelisting-all-remote-resources).